# 'Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).' for a two parameter statement

Tags: spring, prepared-statement, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm following this tutorial to learn about Spring JdbcTemplate, and it has the following example which works fine:

```
public void deleteDog(String name, Long id) {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE FROM dog WHERE name='" + name + "' AND id=" + id);
}
```

But that looks like a SQL Injection vulnerability to me, so I try to rewrite it as the following:

```
public void deleteDog(String name, Long id) {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE FROM dog WHERE name='?' AND id=?", name, id);
}
```

Now I'm getting 'Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).'  But it clearly has two question marks for parameters in the DELETE statement...  Also an update from the same tutorial worked fine in that style with three parameters:

```
    jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO dog(name, rescued, vaccinated) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
            name, rescued, vaccinated);
```

So it doesn't look like I'm mis-using the update method with multiple parameters.  What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `'` surrounding characters when using PreparedStatement's arguments:

```
public void deleteDog(String name, Long id) {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE FROM dog WHERE name=? AND id=?", name, id);
}
```